# How to stream a HTTP Response straight to the network

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, throughput

I am writing a high throughput web service using WCF 4.0 + REST. The web service returns XML responses. The return type of my operation methods are XDocument and WCF takes care of returning the XML. However building the XML response in memory to then return it to the caller isn't very efficient.

I am trying to move away from XmlDocument/XDocument to XmlWriter. In a Console App, I can easily stream a response to a file, but what about WCF? Can I stream the response using the WebOperationContext, HttpContext, returning a stream?

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("New.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs))
{
    FormatResponse(writer, myDate);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Only TCP, IPC, WebHttpBinding and basicHttp bindings support streaming.

Your contract definition

```
[OperationContract]
Stream GetXml();
```

Your service method implementation

```
public Stream GetXml()
{
    string filePath = "document.xml";

    try
    {
        FileStream xmlFileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
        return xmlFileStream;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        // Exception handling logic
    }
}
```

Change your binding configuration on server-side (in this case StreamedResponse)

```
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name = "StreamedHTTP"
               transferMode = "StreamedResponse"
      />
   </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Here is TransferMode enum:

```
public enum TransferMode
{
   Buffered, //default
   Streamed,
   StreamedRequest,
   StreamedResponse
}
```

> **Note:**
>
> - Don't forget to set maxReceivedMessageSize = "some value" on the client-side for large streams
> - When you use streaming, you cannot use message-level transfer security.
> - You cannot use streaming when the contract is configured with SessionMode.Required.
> - When streaming with the TCP binding, you also cannot enable reliable
>     messaging.

Comment: You've forgotten WebHttpBinding: it supports streaming too.

Answer (score 0):

You may combine REST ans WCF streaming. Look at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35982/REST-WCF-and-Streams-Getting-Rid-of-those-Names-Sp), for example.